# Complex if condition with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-geocoder

```
if @near.nil?
  loc, @near, found = get_user_geolocation
else
  loc = GeoKit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(@near)
  found = loc.success
  @near = loc.full_address
end
```

In the first if part, what is going on? I may be not good with syntax, but it made me curious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the `@near.nil?` that confuses you, or the `loc, @near, found = get_user_geolocation`?

Comment: Actually what is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: `loc, @near, found = get_user_geolocation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_user_geolocation` method returns three values: `loc`, `@near` and `found`.

Answer (score 5):

see [Multiple Assignment](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/377861025/multiple-assignment)

```
> a,b,c = [10,20,30] # or a,b,c = 10,20,30
> a => 10 
> b => 20 
> c => 30
```